# Unique Probability Formula — Minecraft Custom Fishing Plugin

Tags: probability

I'm configuring a custom fishing plugin that handles its rarity probabilities in a unqique way. I need to have Common, Uncommon, Rare, Extremely Rare, and Legendary rarities with hit-rates of 70%, 20%, 7.999%, 2%, and 0.0001%, respectively.

Here's how the plugin calculates which fish rarity you get.
When you have a fish on your line, it calculates whether you're getting a Common fish or to roll for an Uncommon fish. If it selects Uncommon, then it will roll again— this time to determine whether you're getting an Uncommon fish or a Rare fish. This continues for each of the groups.

I'm only able to adjust the hit-rate for getting into the next rarity roll; ie. I'm able to set Uncommon to x%, Rare to y%, and so on. But the rarity set for any non-Uncommon group —such as Legendary— is actually the aggregate of all the rolls before it. Using the percentages I have above, the odds of rolling a Legendary fish isn't 0.001%— it's 0.001% of 2% of 7.999% of 20%. I want the rarity of a legendary fish to be exactly 1/10,000!

How can I go about making a formula to solve for the rarities I want? I've never worked with nested(?) probabilities like this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a weird plugin – why don’t they just let you specify the probability distribution?

You need to take the ratio of the desired probability to the remaining probability. At the beginning, the remaining probability is $1$, so the required probability for common is, unsurprisingly, $\frac{0.7}1=0.7$. That leaves $1-0.7=0.3$, so conditional on not having obtained a common fish, the probability for an uncommon fish is

$$\frac{\mathsf P(\text{uncommon})}{\mathsf P(\neg\,\text{common})}=\frac{0.2}{0.3}=\frac23\;.$$

That leaves $1-0.7-0.2=0.3-0.2=0.1$, so the next probability is

$$\frac{\mathsf P(\text{rare})}{\mathsf P(\neg\,\text{common}\cup\neg\,\text{uncommon})}=\frac{0.07999}{0.1}=0.7999\;,$$

and so on.

Comment: Joriki— thank you so much for this! I've worked through it, and I think I completely understand what's going on and why. One last confirming question: when it comes to inputting the variables for the chance of progressing to the next rarity tier, I would be inputting (1 - this ratio), right? The result of this ratio is giving me the probability of catching the fish in that round, and the plugin's variables represent the chance to progress to the next round.

Comment: @Dylan: Yes, sorry, I'd forgotten that that's what you need to enter.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I understood it. Thank you again!!